# How to lock a method only if another method is called

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking

I'm having some kind of data-structure that has to methods.

```
public final class DataStructure {

     private final Map<String> _data = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();

     public void add(final String s) {
          _data.add(s);
     }

     synchronized public void writeToDisk() {
          // code to write _data to disc
          _data.clear();
     }
}
```

In my scenario I have a couple of threads that call DataStructure#add and at some point another thread might call writeToDisk().

Is there a way to ensure that no data get lost while the one thread calls DataStructure#writeToDisk and the others call DataStructure#add, without adding synchronized to DataStructure#add? I don't want to do this, since is\t massively slows my program down and it is pretty unlikely that DataStructure#writeToDisk get invoked.

More precisely, is it possible to lock DataStructure#add for all threads if and only if someone enters writeToDisk and if so how does writeToDisk() ensure that nobody is currently inside the DataStructure#add call?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html

Comment: @JBNizet thank's a lot. Btw. is it possible to call the write-locked method within the read-locked method?

Comment: No. The javadoc of [ReentrantReadWriteLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html) says: *a writer can acquire the read lock, but not vice-versa*

Comment: @JBNizet sry for that question ... just read that after I posted it. Thx agian